# Setup Mysql C++ Connector in Netbeans on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to get the mysql c++ connector to work. I am using netbeans on windows.

The error I am getting is:

> undefined reference to `_imp__get_driver_instance'

Source code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        driver = get_driver_instance();

    } catch(sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout << "ERR: " << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler settings:

[image]

Linker settings:

[image]
[image]

I have tried both the .dll and the .lib file but there is noe difference in the error.

Build log:

```
"/E/Programing_Libs/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/Utvikling/c++/CppApplication_1'
"/E/Programing_Libs/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/Utvikling/c++/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/E/Programing_Libs/Mysql\ C++\ Connector/lib/opt -lmysqlcppconn
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
D:\Utvikling\c++\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `_imp__get_driver_instance'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Utvikling/c++/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Utvikling/c++/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Everything is the 64 bit version. Has anyone ever successfully setup c++ connector on windows in netbeans? Cant find much about it on google. Getting same error with sql::mysql namespace.

Do anoyone know what I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Posibly you need to use libmysql.dll from mysql server lib directory?